# c# xml deserialized error in xml document (1,40)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have a string that needs to deserialized and it is a response

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
<soap:Body>
  <TestResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">
     <TestResult>
            <code>1</code>
            <msg>Message was successfully sent</msg>
            <sent />
    </TestResult>
  </TestResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

here is my deserialization code

```
                string s = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
                Test_Response resp = new Test_Response();
                using (var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(s))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test_Response));
                    resp = (Test_Response)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                }
                return s;
```

here is my class

```
   [Serializable(), XmlRoot("TestResult")]
   public class Test_Response
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string msg { get; set; }
        public string sent { get; set; }
    }
```

then the error message is

> There is an error in XML document (1, 40).

inner exception is

> `<Envelope xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> was not expected.`

can anyone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Small change in your XML file: extra `/` at the end of `xmlns`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <TestResult>
        <code>1</code>
        <msg>Message was successfully sent</msg>
        <sent />
      </TestResult>
    </TestResponse>

  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and create Model like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TestResult", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public class TestResult
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "code", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "msg", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string Msg { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sent", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string Sent { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TestResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public class TestResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TestResult", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public TestResult TestResult { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TestResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public TestResponse TestResponse { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soap { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
    }
```

then try your code it'll work. I have tested this locally.
Happy coding...

Comment: If this helped solve your problem you can mark this as answer.

Comment: I would be interested to know what causes this.